# IBM Cloud: Required IAM access policy to see user-specific authorizations (policies)?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-iam

In IBM Cloud, I have an IAM Access Group for security admins. What policy do I need to grant to have their members READ access to user-specific authorizations, i.e., access policies granted to a user, not an Access Group?

The account owner can see those authorizations by, e.g., the [List Policies API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-policy-management#list-policies). The security admin, when calling that API, either receives an empty list or only a partial list. The Access Group for security admins already has Administrator privilege for IAM Identity Service and IAM Access Group Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see access policies, the security administrators and hence their related Access Group need *[*Viewer** privilege on all resources and services](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-userroles) that are directly "authorized" to users or service IDs. It is not enough to have **Viewer** or even **Administrator** role on **IAM Access Groups Service**, **Viewer** on all **Account Management** as well as on all IAM-enabled services is required.

The following would give [Viewer on Account Management services when using Terraform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-iam-resources#iam-access-group-policy-input):

```
resource "ibm_iam_access_group_policy" "cloud-security-admins-account_viewer" {
  access_group_id = ibm_iam_access_group.cloud-security-admins.id
  account_management = true
  roles = [ "Viewer" ]
}
```

And the next Terraform snippet could be used to give Viewer on all IAM-enabled services:

```
resource "ibm_iam_access_group_policy" "cloud-security-admins-viewall-resources" {
  access_group_id = ibm_iam_access_group.cloud-security-admins.id
  roles = [ "Viewer" ]
    resources {
    resource_type = "resource-group"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the policies are based on a resource group you might need Viewer access to the resource group.  In terraform it would be something like this:

```
resource "ibm_iam_access_group_policy" "shared_policy" {
  access_group_id = ibm_iam_access_group.shared.id
  roles           = ["Viewer"]
  resources {
    resource_type = "resource-group"
    resource      = ibm_resource_group.shared.id
  }
}
```

New resource groups could be added in the future...

Comment: Not necessarily based on a resource group, it could be anything directly assigned to a user (or service ID).